# Equivalent of using a ssh tunnel

Tags: postgresql, ssh, docker, rds, ssh-tunnel

Using virtual hosts rather than deployed Docker container it was a normal work process for me to create ssh tunnels in order to access delimited machines from my local box. For instance connect with my `psql` client to a Postgres instance which I could only reach from a bastion box.

With Docker everything is boxes away even more. Is there an equivalent for doing the same but with Docker? Tunnel through the Docker instance to the RDS instance?

Answer (score 0):

You use the [docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/) to connect to a running container. For instance...

To log into a db running in a container you can use (from your local machine)

```
docker exec -it mypsqlcontainer psql -U username dbname
```

I personally almost never have to ssh into the host. Everything can be done through the docker CLI.

Comment: Great, so I also need to combine this with a command which looks up the docker container id?

Comment: It's easier if you name your containers and use the name instead of the id.

eg:

    docker run -d --name mysqlcontainer mysql:latest

Then you can use my `docker exec ..` line above without having to figure out the container id.

Of course this only works when you have 1 instance of each container. You can't specify `--name` when you use `--scale` to create multiple containers for a given service.

Comment: SSHing to the host allows to use convenient tools to work with SQL (JetBrains products, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can make ssh-tunnel to the docker host. DB port must be accessible from docker host (i.e. using "-p" docker run option).

If you prefer not publishing DB port you can create jumpbox container with ssh server, publish port 22 on this container and user container linking to link jumpbox container with DB container.